# SQL Server - Filtering Results of Cross Apply With Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I am trying to limit the results of what is selected in the cross apply by the @numRows parameter, which does not work. I am able to reduce this later by using the 'Row_Num' field, but would like improve this. There are a some other fields, but this the general idea. Any thoughts / suggestions?

```
declare @numRows as int = 2
select
t1.Field_1
,t1.Field_2
,t1.Quantity
,[Row_Num] = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.Field_1, t1.Field_2 order by Quantity desc)
from
spTable as t1
cross apply
(
 select top (@numRows)
 Field_1, Field_2  
 from 
 spTable as t2
 where
 t1.Field_2 = t2.Field_2
 and
 t1.Field_1= t2.Field_1
) as t
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Does it return an error?  Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Syntactically I don't see any mistakes here. Can you add sample data and expected output to clarify what you are trying to do.